# Erroneous .htaccess file breaks Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a PHP project up and running using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I wanted to set a few things using `.htaccess`. Unfortunately I misspelled something, causing a configuration error of the Web site. After removing the `.htaccess` file again, the Web site was still not working. I tried redeploying the project, restarting the app server(s) and even rebuilding the entire Elastic Beanstalk environment without luck.

In the end, I created a new Elastic Beanstalk application, and then it worked fine. But now I've written something wrong in the `.htaccess` file again, the new application has stopped working, even though I have removed the erroneous `.htaccess` file.

What might be causing this issue? And how can I fix it?

**Edit**

I've checked the logs `/var/log/httpd/access_log` and `/var/log/httpd/error_log`, but they have not been updated since the Web site broke down.

Comment: Sounds like it is just a caching issue? I imagine you have caching enabled in your `.htaccess` file. Clear your cache and check the website again. I think your browser is simply loading the old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the `.htaccess` file that caused the issue turned out to be a permanent redirect (301) from `http` to `https`. But `https` was not yet set up on the server, and hence the request failed. Since it was a 301 redirect, my computer stored it and performed it on any subsequent request, regardless of the browser.